# Deploy Ratchet Server on google app engine and listen

Tags: php, sockets, google-app-engine, websocket, ratchet

I am creating a ratchet chat application. It is currently on my localhost 8080 however I want to connect it to my google app engine project what can I do

Here is my Ratchet code:

```
class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {

        protected $clients;

        public function __construct() {
            $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
        }

        public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
            // Store the new connection to send messages to later
            $this->clients->attach($conn);

            echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
        }

        public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
            $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
            echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n"
                , $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');

    foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
        if ($from !== $client) {
            // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
            $client->send($msg . " Hello ");
        }
    }
}

public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
    $this->clients->detach($conn);

    echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
}

public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
    echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";

    $conn->close();
}
}


$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new Chat()
        )
    ),
    8080
);
$server->run();
```

Does App Engine support that, if not what other alternatives can I use to deploy my chat on a live application